# discord.py бот не выполняет команду

Tags: python, discord.py

если человек изменил свой текст бот должен отправлять текстовое сообщение (Сообщение было изменено! старое сообщение -> новое сообщение)

```
@bot.event 
async def on_massage_edit(before, after): 
    if before.content == after.content:
        return
    await before.channel.send(f"Сообщение было изменено!\n{before.content} -> {after.content}")
    bot.process_commands
    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего ваш код не работает из-за данных ошибок:

1. **Вы неправильно указали название "ивента", нужно** `on_massage_edit` **поменять на** `on_message_edit`.
2. `bot.process_commands` **нужно изменить на** `await bot.process_commands()`

*Из [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands):*

При вызове функции `process_commands()`, нужно указать параметр:

`message(discord.Message) -> Сообщение для обработки команды.`

Comment: При вызове функции process_commands(), нужно указать параметр:

message(discord.Message) -> Сообщение для обработки команды.
куда точнее это вставить

Comment: @Marlin09, `await bot.process_commands(after) `